# Encryption type number converted to encrypted string

Tags: javascript, python, vba, selenium, encryption

During surfing a website, I noticed that the url which looks like that `https://gis.paci.gov.kw/Search/10670235` converted to `https://kfappsrv.paci.gov.kw/kuwaitfinder/server/api/search/search?params=4MRYKZEnKubG40jmQ%2FP9wuoMjAsIwzarvsdoK8qDXntw3hjyw5%2BRrY4YSLMXEZ6RrtGEotWTzLRoDR0by5IpbFtPda2ZvhVpIm9FcT0zVMyitij0qsh8XUIBZs1pWUKR7lJe1G%2BlTudmekv3wZ0wKPyNszUNP5zkEEqgexrLx6E5Abn2Iz6Qg%2BUuAD5pyIHsuII%2BUboF0fpoLW7AkhuhE8RnmXa7wyUkUplCkr8a8iSYm1OUuEFl4Eq0krPe7wv8mVx4AVlzpauLzplljAleWa%2BqDk5F7piKQVYM1wOLvotWDjHr50BC4jnzrXdI9NAmx1cs9mUhXiWRhmDyaPuWmU9e3rDquc9M9iinXV28Z4e2owmx1L8v6MNxbxoLuERPyWXJTWDsirMvaczaYwQkLcwV6YPInik%2FlRyYGhyH7Fquxc07ojR1%2Bcqa%2Flb26QSjw7UDMI1GoQ24gywn206h0l%2FkxCuzseHXzqbCM01eH02uW%2F4bhQHe1tBYAtnatYFgs76VT%2BeAMzVLVfijeMgab%2FvWcPZ%2Bw75jI553L0bYImL1YieUKBEN7DkA8QZdLV6YfUh99LXm7niD%2BsUmzuaOitOvReFo55jV%2BWUoHuayZ0id7Hz1dWc2oc%2B28sPcXOzf2Z9OJauCb7w%3D`
So I guess the number related to the url is encrypted in specific way
I have curios to know what type of encryption is this?

Comment: It's not "encrypted", it's a query/id that server uses to find the actual url stored in the database.

Comment: So you mean if I use for example requests in python and get the url, I can get the same url that is rendered from the server?

Comment: Yes, usually server returns redirection (`location`) header, so basically all you need to do is capture headers to get real url. (You can see it in dev tools of your browser)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at how url work in general from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL). In your case, when you access the first url, they redirected you to the 2nd url. In the 2nd url, there is a query text, denoted with the `?params=`.

Comment: My target is to know how the server convert the first url to the second url form? I have inspected the Network but didn't find a clue.

Comment: There are many ways, and it need not necessarily be converted by the server. It can be a simple frontend javascript redirect, and that would be evident if you inspected the source code. But since you did not find anything from inspecting the source code, we can conclude that the conversion was done by the backend server, before the new url was sent to redirect the client. However, it is impossible to derive the backend conversion logic as we do not have access to the backend source code. We can only make educated guesses, and the database method mentioned by @vanowm may be a possible method.

Comment: Can I share the out HTML of the page?

Comment: May I clarify what you mean by share the out HTML?

Comment: I thought sharing the outer HTML would help to get the whole process.

Comment: I don't think so. HTML is a frontend language, but by the way you describe it, the link conversion happens on the backend, which you do not have access to.